# Android json shows String cannot converted to json array error

Tags: android, json, http

Hi I am working with android.I had created an app which use json for getting a value from the database.I tested my app in xamp local host successfully.But when I am trying to connect to my server,it not works properly and shows error "04-01 14:48:48.308: E/log_tag(695): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ﻿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
"
I cant find out the error please help me, thanks in advance

here is my code

```
       try{

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("server link");

                    HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    HttpEntity entity = response1.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();


                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");

            }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());


                }
                try
                {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                                Log.w("Lengh","in buffered reader while");
                        }
                        is.close();

                        result2=sb.toString();

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                       Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());


                }
                try
                {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result2);


                      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                          App_id=json_data.getString("app_id");

                          String key=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");


                         if (getIntent().hasExtra("key")) {

                             if(key.compareTo(App_id)==0)
                             {

                                 flag=1;
                                 break;

                                //setContentView(R.layout.home); 
                             }

                         } else {

                                finish();
                            }
```

Comment: `Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray` What you get is a String not a JSONArray. check your response

Comment: I get the string from server database

Comment: @Bennett Can you post that response.

Comment: I cannot get result2 from server.How can I resolve this?? It works ok with local server

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your web server is not returning valid JSON as your code looks ok. I would start by taking a look at the server response e.g. log the contents of result2 and see if it contains valid JSON.

Comment: yes you are right. I cannot get result from server.But it looks working in local server , then what is the problem here??

Comment: I print my result2. It shows some unused character like  !>>  before the result2. Why??